# Dúvida sobre análise sintática da orações interrogativas

Tags: pronomes, função-sintática

Estou estudando pronomes interrogativos e gostaria de entender como achar o sujeito destas orações, haja vista que é um pouco diferente pra mim analisar frases interrogativas.
*Ex:*
O que é o mundo? [Nesta frase, qual o sujeito e qual a função sintática do termo "o" e do termo "que"?]

Comment: [tenho visto, não haja visto]

Comment: O termo **que** é o sujeito pronominal da oração; já o termo **o**, o adjunto adnominal.

Comment: Por que diz que o "o" seria adjunto, @ValdeirPsr?

Answer (score 1):

Depende da frase! Em uma frase como:

> "O que comeu a comida?"

o pronome "*o que*" substitui aquilo que comeu a comida, como uma gaivota ou algo assim, afinal é um pronome, neste caso, com a função de sujeito da oração.

Numa frase como:

> "o que ele comeu?"

o pronome "o que" substiui o que foi comido, o objeto da frase, então este pronome pode ter outras funções sintáticas dependendo da frase, basta entender o que está acontecendo.

Adiciono também que o pronome inteiro é "**o que**", não é dividido!

Comment: O que quer dizer com sua última afirmação, Ergative? Pergunto porque o pronome parece ser apenas o "que", enquanto o "o" seria [1] uma partícula expletiva, não parte do pronome. Outras fontes [e.g., 2, 3] também se referem ao "o que" e congêneres como expressões.   
   
[1] https://www.clubedoportugues.com.br/pronomes-interrogativos/   
[2] https://www.normaculta.com.br/pronomes-interrogativos/   
[3] https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/pronomes-interrogativos-sentido-uso.htm

Comment: Então, aí temos uma questão diacronia vs sincronia. Considerando a ausência de expletivos foneticamente realizados na língua portuguesa e a inseparabilidade das duas formas, tem-se a noção de uma unidade atual com uma origem a partir de dois termos. Da mesma forma que considaramos "porque" uma coisa só, não uma preposição + uma conjunção, e sim uma única conjunção.

Comment: Mas o fato de o "o" em "o que" ser dispensável, ao contrário do "por" em "porque", não é uma diferença importante?

Comment: Mas é como eu disse, o "o" não é bem dispensável, pense assim: "o bolo foi o que ele comeu" e "*o bolo foi que ele comeu", esta última não funciona. Quando é uma interrogativa e se usa o "que" pode ser um aracaísmo ou, de fato, uma variação. A questão é que não há muita motivação sincrônica para tratá-lo como expletivos, chega a ser quase uma falácia etimológica, uma vez que pode ser esta a sua origem, mas hoje, não representa o que é, fundiram-se. Há quem diga hoje, e até no português quinhentista, frases como "não fiz isso, que eu estava muito cansado", sendo o "que" = "porque".

Comment: Normalmente estas gramáticas escolares etc utilizam-se da chamada "gramáticas tradicional" que se baseia nos metodos, muitas vezes, obsoletos de tratarem, teorizarem e explicarem a língua, métodos que hoje sabemos serem falíveis, no entanto, é claro, tem muitos méritos na formação dos estudos modernos das línguas! :)

Comment: Obrigado pela discussão, Ergative! Não tenho fundamento teórico para me decidir entre a tua posição ("o que" como entidade única) e a do Valdeir Psr ("que", sujeito e "o", adjunto).

Comment: Não sei por que se classificaria o "o" como adjunto. Vou lhe perguntar :)